# When screen-sharing with docusign Android SDK, black screen

Tags: android, docusignapi

I have the docusign android sdk integrated with my project.

When I try to screen share via zoom it shows a black screen even when I set mode to DEBUG and environment to DEMO.

Is there a way to allow screen sharing in a debug build of this app?

[image: Black Screen]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable screen share by invoking the following SDK API:
`DocuSign.getInstance().allowScreenCapture(true)`